# Remove model name from ember data json

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember data send data to the server with the model name embedded.

```
{
    "part" {
       "name" : "test1",
       "quantity" : 12
    }
}
```

I want the "part" field removed from the response so it would look like:

```
{
   "name" : "test1",
   "quantity" : 12
}
```

I need this to be generic so it will work for any model in my store.

---

ok I found the part that does in RESTAdapter.

```
  serializeIntoHash: function(data, type, record, options) {
    var root = underscore(decamelize(type.typeKey));
    data[root] = this.serialize(record, options);
  },
```

I tried to remove the root part

```
serializeIntoHash: function(data, type, record, options) {
    data = this.serialize(record, options);
}
```

But it does not work, it response with {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/san650/ember-cli-page-object/issues/153

`Ember.merge` is deprecated, use `Ember.assign`

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    Ember.assign(hash, this.serialize(record, options));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

OK found it: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/771

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(record, options));
  }
});
```

Comment: Seems that Ember.assign may now be preferable to Ember.merge:
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-shims/blob/master/vendor/ember-cli-shims/app-shims.js#L144